# Converting arithmetic sequence from explicit to recursive form

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have explicit form of arithmetic sequence $h(n) = 1 + 4n$ where I have to convert it to recursive form to find the first term and the common difference. I did it like this:

$h(1) = 1$

$h(n) = h(n-1) + 4$

But software says I'm wrong (with the first term of $1$ and common difference of $4$). Yet, when I check it, I get the same common difference with both ways:

$h(1) = 1 + 4 \cdot 1 = 5$

$h(2) = 1 + 4 \cdot 2 = 9$

$h(3) = 1 + 4 \cdot 3 = 13$

And for the recursive form:

$h(2) = 1 + 4 = 5$

$h(3) = 5 + 4 = 9$

$h(4) = 9 + 4 = 13$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `h(1)=1` Where did you get that from? It should be $h(1) = 5\,$ by the given formula.

Comment: or start it with $n=0$, so $h(0)=1$